# Can I choose an Build Agent as Parameter in Team city?

Tags: teamcity

Each time I ran the build - I check a few parameters, but can I also have the same procedure for Agents?
For example: I have two Agents - each time I press run - I can choose between Agent1 and Agent2.

Thanks

Comment: Please ignore this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can select agent under General tab on Run. See below screenshot:
[image]